# css: Issue in resizing window in html5

Tags: css, html

This is code i tried:

```
*
{
    box-sizing:border-box;  
}
div,body,html,h1,nav,article,footer,header{display:block;}
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#wrapper
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.title p
{
    text-align:center;
    color:darkgray;
}
img
{
    vertical-align:middle;  
    margin:0;
}
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
}
 #fixme
{    
    height : 65px;
    position: relative;
    overflow : hidden;
}
#animate-area 
{ 
    height: 122%;
    width: 2538px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -15px;
    background-image: url('http://s30.postimg.org/qnju89rkx/banner.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 30s linear infinite;
}
    /* Put your css in here */
    @keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
 }
#logo img
 {
    position:absolute;  
    z-index:999;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-top: -22px;
 }   
 h1
 {  
    text-align:center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom: inherit;
 }
 .header-pgf
{
    width: 67%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin: auto;   
    margin-top:15px;
}
.title
{
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:960px;    


}
.nav
{       
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b9b9b9), to(#000));
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, red, yellow);
    height:45px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.nav ul
{
    text-align:center;  

}
.nav ul li
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav > ul li:first-child a
{
    background-color:Red;
}
.nav > ul li:first-child a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.nav li:hover a 
{
    background-color: red;
}
.nav li a 
{
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav 
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none;
} 
.flexslider .slides img 
{
    width: 960px; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display: block;
}
.flex-pauseplay span 
{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.flexslider .slides > li 
{
    display: none; 
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.slides:after 
{
    content: "."; 
    display: block; 
    clear: both; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    line-height: 0; 
    height: 0;
} 
html[xmlns] .slides 
{
    display: block;
} 
* html .slides 
{
    height: 1%;
}
.flexslider 
{ 
    border: 4px solid #fff; 
    position: relative;  
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
    zoom: 1;
    margin-top: 20px;
} 
.flex-viewport 
{
    max-height: 2000px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; 
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport 
{
    max-height: 200px;
}
.flexslider .slides 
{
    zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides 
{
    border-right:10px;
}
.flex-direction-nav 
{
    *height: 0;
    width:400px !important;
}
.flex-direction-nav a 
{
    width: 60px; 
    height: 60px; 
    display: block;  
    no-repeat 0 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    z-index: 10; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    text-indent: -9999px; 
    opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled 
{ 
    filter:alpha(opacity=20); 
    cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-nav 
{
    width: 100%;  
    bottom: -40px; 
    text-align: center; 
    float:left;
    margin-top:-200px;
}
.flex-control-nav 
{
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -40px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-weight:bold;
    color:darkgray;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.flex-control-nav li 
{
    margin: 0 6px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    zoom: 2; 
}
.flex-control-nav li:hover 
{ 
    color:#000;  
}
.flex-control-nav .flex-active 
{  
    cursor: default; 
    color:#000;
    opacity: .7; 
}

.column-layout
{
    padding-top: 73px;  
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1300px;  
}
section
{
    padding: 0px 40px;
}
.column-layout p
{   
    color:  darkgray;
}
.column-layout h3, .column-layout img
{
    margin-left: 40px;  

}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.column-count-1, .column-count-2, .column-count-3, .column-count-4 {
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
}
.column-count-1, .column-count-2, .column-count-3, .column-count-4 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.4pt;
}
.featured
{   
    background-color: darkgray;
    color:#fff; 
    padding:10px;
    display: flex;  
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.featured-pgf
{
    float:left;
    clear:both; 


}
input[type=text] {
    border-radius:0px;
    padding: 14px 18px 14px 18px;
    margin-left: 151px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 260px;
}

form 
{
    float:right;
    margin:0;   
}
 .footer-link 
 {
    background-color: darkgray;
    line-height: 9pt;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    padding-left: 47px;}
.footer-link a:first-child 
{   
    border-left: 0px;   
}
.footer-link 
{
    text-align:center;
}
.footer-link a
{
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 9pt;
    line-height: 9pt;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.footer-link a:hover
{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:underline;  
}
#footer
{
    width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;  
}
.copyright
{
    margin-left: 33px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: darkgray;
    float:left;
}
#footer img
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:right;
    margin: 4px;    
}
```

This is JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6deqxyk4/

When resize the window, it will shows like this: http://s27.postimg.org/5p20dklg3/Untitled_1_copy.png

May i know how to align the page when resizing the window, I need to display centring all the content of page.

Mostly i tried, but somewhat missing, please help with my errors.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: body{ margin:0 auto;}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6deqxyk4/2/

Comment: @himanshu: nothing change from your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
   .wrapper{
      width:900px;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto; 
    }
    #header{
      width:100%;
      // give it orange background here
    }
    #footer{
      width:100%;
     // give it background here
    }

 <div id="header">
     <div class="wrapper">
         // navigation bar here
     </div>
 </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
     // page content here
  </div>


 <div id="footer">
     <div class="wrapper">
         // navigation bar here
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I already tried like your answer, when i use width for wrapper, the navigation bar in header is not shoe as full width right?

Comment: You need to put navigation bar inside the wrapper element.

Comment: @ Paramore: When i use width:960px; in wrapper, it shows like this, when resizing http://imgur.com/8d35yUF. but i need header and footer like this when resizing, http://postimg.org/image/wfvm08tof/2a87e2c2/

Comment: Just create class wrapper (don't use ID) and give it style .wrapper{ width:960px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}. You can use that class in both header and footer. Put wrapper inside another div in header and footer. This is kind of tip.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file add a div like  http://jsfiddle.net/6deqxyk4/3/

```
<div id="page">
```

begin this at the beginning of your content and close it at the end of all content 
Then add this to your css

```
#page{
width:980px;
margin:auto;
}
```

this will solve it